# Perl + moose: Can't call method "x" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, moose

I'm just trying to do this: http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/08/youre-already-using-dependency-injection.html.  Really not deviating too much at all from that example code.

Here's what I've got:

```
package M;
use Moose;
use Exporter;
use Data::Dumper;

sub new {
    print "M::new!\n";
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub x {
    my ($self, $stuff) = @_;

    print Dumper($stuff);
}


#################################


package Foo;
use Moose;
use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = ();

has 'mS', is => 'ro', default => sub { M->new };

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub bar {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;

    # do stuff here...
    # ...


    my $foo = $self->mS;
    # this...
    $foo->x($data);
    # ...causes "Can't call method "x" on an undefined value at Foo.pm line 45."
}

1;
```

It's worth noting that the `M::new!` message never appears, so I'm guessing that it's never reached.  What's going on?

Comment: With [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose), one doesn't write `sub new`.

Answer (score 2):

With [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose), you shouldn't write `sub new`. Moose provides the constructor for you.

Also, using [Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Exporter) makes no sense with object-oriented modules. The following program works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{   package M;
    use Moose;
    use Data::Dumper;

    sub x {
        my ($self, $stuff) = @_;
        print Dumper($stuff);
    }
}


{   package Foo;
    use Moose;

    has mS => ( is => 'ro', default => sub { 'M'->new } );

    sub bar {
        my ($self, $data) = @_;
        my $foo = $self->mS;
        $foo->x($data);
    }
}

my $foo = 'Foo'->new;
$foo->bar('test');
```

Comment: Where, specifically, do you mean, please?

Comment: Thank you.  The problem was exactly as you said - no need for "sub new".  In fact the sub in question seems to bu... stuff up the whole thing.  Either "sub new" in M or Foo seems to do it.

Comment: @DiamondGeezer: "Thank you" on StackOverflow = vote up / accept :-)

Comment: Indeed, but one needs more rep before one is able to do that :-D

Comment: Lots of OO modules export constants, though `use Exporter; @ISA = qw( Exporter );` has been replaced with `use Exporter qw( import );`

Answer (score 1):

You have a solution - don't write your own `new()` method when you're using Moose. But there's one other little point that might be worth making.

The constructor that Moose will give you for your Foo class will work pretty well as a drop-in replacement for your `new()` method. But the one that Moose gives you for your M class will be missing a feature - it won't print your "M::new!\n" message. How do we get round that?

In Moose, you can define a `BUILD()` method which will be called immediately after `new()` has returned a new object. That's a good place to put any extra initialisation that your new object needs. It would also be be a good place for your `print()` call (although it happens **after** object construction, not before - so it's not an exact replacement).